# Convert Color Atribute to Face Delete Color Attribute

Tags: vertex-colors

When I convert Domain from vertex to Face of my Color Attribute, it delete it...

Why ?

Thanks !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is not deleted, but not used in the viewport as attribute for viewport shading.

Answer (score 0):

The interface for color attributes requires a vertex or face corner domain. The attribute is not removed, it simply isn't displayed under *Color Attributes*, and its colors are not displayed in viewport - but the attribute still exists and you can show it in shading:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But I know this, I can force display to face in Evee with geometry Node but It should work in viewport workbench... it seems to be just not implemented...

Comment: @BLenjamin yep, not implemented.